# Artículo definido, "el", como sujeto indefinido

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres, artículos

En el sitio web https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disimulo, encontré la siguiente oración:

> Acción o actitud del que disimula, del que intenta que no se note lo que realmente hace, siente, piensa, etc.

Por desgracia no entiendo "del que" en esta oración. Sospecho que el artículo definido en "del que" (= "de el que") indica un sujeto indefinido, así que la frase anterior se la podría reformular algo así:

> Acción o actitud de uno (o de alguien o de la persona) que disimula...

Sin embargo, no encontré tal explicación de "del que" en la web. Solo encontré ejemplos en los que el artículo definido se refiere al nombre antecedente, como

> La mujer de la que te hablo es famosa. o El dinero del que dispone el banco.

Creo que estas explicaciones no pueden aplicarse a la oración anterior porque

- tanto "acción" como "aptitud" son sustantivos femeninos
- "disimular" no lleva un complemento preposicional
- la oración no tendría un sujeto.

Pues, ¿es correcto que el artículo definido "el" se usa a veces como sujeto indefinido? Dicho sea de paso que "la" tendría más sentido para mí porque "la persona" es femenina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, cuando dices *«acción o actitud del que disimula»*, el sujeto de la oración subordinada es *el que*; la palabra *que* es un pronombre relativo que en estos casos debe ir precedido por un artículo. El género del artículo será

- masculino (*el*), si nos referimos a algo o alguien de género masculino (un varón, un animal macho, un objeto de género gramatical masculino), o bien si no sabemos de qué sexo/género es, ya que el masculino es el género por defecto;
- femenino (*la*), si nos referimos a algo o alguien (generalmente ya nombrado antes) de género gramatical femenino;
- neutro (*lo*), si nos referimos a abstracciones.

Por supuesto, si se trata de más de una persona u objeto usaremos las formas en plural (*los que, las que*).

*El que* y *la que* pueden reemplazarse por *quien* si se trata de personas; *que* puede también cambiarse (a veces) por *cual*. En plural esto es *quienes* y *cuales* respectivamente. El artículo se puede reemplazar también, por *aquel* (*aquella* en femenino, etc.).

En *«acción o actitud del que disimula»*, *del que* es *de + el que*. La preposición *de* no es parte de la subordinada, sino que relaciona el sujeto de la misma (*el que disimula* = "la persona que disimula") con *acción o actitud*. Así como decimos

- *la acción d**el ejército***
- *la actitud de **tu hermano***

podemos decir

- *la acción d**el que disimula***
- *la actitud d**el que intenta que no se note lo que piensa***

Comment: Para mí la clave es que "el que" se puede usar sin un antecedente, con el significado "la persona que" (la mayoría de los ejemplos que he encontrado contienen un antecedente) y que el masculino es el género por defecto.
Considero interesante también este artículo sobre el tema (https://elmundoendatos.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/el-genero-por-defecto/).